# Что значат кавычки перед словом?

Tags: кавычки

Указать «в соответствии с условиями закупочной документации» значит, что я указываю именно то, что в кавычках или в переносном смысле? Открыть и указать оттуда?

Answer (score 2):

В данном контексте это, скорее всего, будет означать, что вы цитируете эту фразу откуда-либо.